# Criteria query filter by object type

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm using jpa criteria query.

Is it possible to filter an entity by the type of some of it's atributes?

let me explain:
I have an entity (let's call it Child) that extends from another entity (let's call it Father).

A third entity Entity1 has an attribute Father (which in some cases could also be Child).

Is there some way to retrieve only those Entity1 which Father attribute is a Child?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried it, but Query-by-example(QBE) might be helpful

Comment: maybe, but QBE is not standard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used a subquery of Child , didn't find a better solution.